# U-boot could not find a valid device tree

Tags: arm, u-boot, device-tree

I have a problem: my device (an [Atmel SAMA5D27 Xplained](http://www.atmel.com/devices/ATSAMA5D27.aspx) board) won't boot after my attempt to flash a new device tree.

Here's what I did (details are at the end of this message):

1. I downloaded the [Linux4SAM source tree from Github (tag linux4sam_5.3)](https://github.com/linux4sam/linux-at91/tree/linux4sam_5.3). I used this tag since that is the one that was installed when I got the device.
2. I made changes to the file `arch/arm/boot/dts/at91-sama5d2_xplained.dts` to enable the SPI1 device (and disable the SDMMC1 device since it is conflicting with the SPI1 pins). I saved the file in the same directory as `at91-sama5d2_xplained_custom.dts` and modified the Makefile accordingly.
3. I compiled (from the root directory of the source tree) with the following command: `$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- dtbs`. A new DTB was generated.
4. I verified the size of the DTB file with the `file` command, which told be the DTB is 30796 bytes.
5. I flashed the DTB to the devices with the [SAM-BA utility](http://www.atmel.com/tools/ATMELSAM-BAIN-SYSTEMPROGRAMMER.aspx), which was successful, but reported that 30976 bytes were flashed.
6. I rebooted the device, which got stuck in the U-boot environment. This was to be expected, since the DTB got changed. I updated the `bootcmd` to reflect the new size of the DTB (30796 = 0x784c), but it still won't boot.

Here's the result from `printenv` after my update (which I saved with `saveenv`):

```
=> printenv
bootargs=console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 rw rootfstype=ext4 rootwait
bootcmd=sf probe 0; sf read 0x21000000 0x70000 0x784c; sf read 0x22000000 0x7c000 0x3636a8; bootz 0x22000000 - 0x21000000
bootdelay=1
ethact=gmac0
ethaddr=fc:c2:3d:02:f4:e9
stderr=serial
stdin=serial
stdout=serial

Environment size: 309/8188 bytes
```

Note that I only updated the size in the first `sf read` command of `bootcmd`. It used to read `sf read 0x21000000 0x70000 0x77c8`, which corresponds to the size of the DTB that I get from the original `at91-sama5d2_xplained.dts` file.

Here's the error that I got:

```
SF: Detected AT25DF321 with page size 256 Bytes, erase size 4 KiB, total 4 MiB
device 0 offset 0x70000, size 0x784c
SF: 30796 bytes @ 0x70000 Read: OK
device 0 offset 0x7c000, size 0x3636a8
SF: 3552936 bytes @ 0x7c000 Read: OK
Kernel image @ 0x22000000 [ 0x000000 - 0x3636a8 ]
ERROR: Did not find a cmdline Flattened Device Tree
Could not find a valid device tree
```

Naturally, my question is: what did I do wrong?

I have some hypotheses, which I tried:

1. I got the size wrong: I tried to use 0x7900 in the `bootcmd` (corresponding to the 30976 bytes that SAM-BA reported), but this didn't help.
2. I flashed to the wrong address: I'm not entirely sure what the address `0x21000000` is in `sf read` in `bootcmd`, but from the example files that were provided with SAM-BA I inferred that 0x70000 was correct. Changing `0x21000000` to `0x0` doesn't help. Changing the SAM-BA write command to write at `0x21070000` results in an error that it cannot write past the end of memory.
3. My DTB is wrong. I don't think I'm doing particularly strange things in my DTS file, and since it compiles I assume it is at least in a format that should be readable.

Any help/advice/pointers/etc. is very much appreciated, as I now have an unbootable device... I'm also worried that if I flashed to the wrong address, I broke all kinds of stuff that I'm not aware of.

---

**Details**

DTS file:

```
/dts-v1/;
#include "at91-sama5d2_xplained_common.dtsi"

/ {
    model = "Atmel SAMA5D2 Xplained";
    compatible = "atmel,sama5d2-xplained", "atmel,sama5d2", "atmel,sama5";

    ahb {
        sdmmc1: sdio-host@b0000000 {        
            status = "disabled"; /* conflict with spi1 */
        };

        apb {
            can0: can@f8054000 {
                status = "okay";
            };

            can1: can@fc050000 {
                status = "okay";
            };

            spi1: spi@fc000000 {
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_spi1_default>;
                status = "okay";
            };

            pinctrl@fc038000 {
                pinctrl_spi1_default: spi1_default {
                    pinmux = <PIN_PA22__SPI1_SPCK>,
                         <PIN_PA23__SPI1_MOSI>,
                         <PIN_PA24__SPI1_MISO>,
                         <PIN_PA25__SPI1_NPCS0>;
                    bias-disable;
                };
            };           
        };
    };
};
```

Compilation of the DTB:

```
$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- dtbs
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[1]: 'include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
  CHK     include/generated/bounds.h
  CHK     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  DTC     arch/arm/boot/dts/at91-sama5d2_xplained_custom.dtb
```

Verification of the DTB file size:

```
$ file arch/arm/boot/dts/at91-sama5d2_xplained_custom.dtb
arch/arm/boot/dts/at91-sama5d2_xplained_custom.dtb: Device Tree Blob version 17, size=30796, boot CPU=0, string block size=1692, DT structure block size=29048
```

SAM-BA flash command output:

```
# sam-ba -p serial:ttyACM0:115200 -b sama5d2-xplained -a serialflash -c write:at91-sama5d2_xplained_custom.dtb:0x70000
Opening serial port 'ttyACM0'
Connection opened.
Detected memory size is 4194304 bytes.
Executing command 'write:at91-sama5d2_xplained_custom.dtb:0x70000'
Added 180 bytes of padding to align to page size
Wrote 30976 bytes at address 0x00070000 (100.00%)
Connection closed.
```

SAM-BA trying to write past the end of memory:

```
# sam-ba -p serial:ttyACM0:115200 -b sama5d2-xplained -a serialflash -c write:at91-sama5d2_xplained_custom.dtb:0x21070000
Opening serial port 'ttyACM0'
Connection opened.
Detected memory size is 4194304 bytes.
Executing command 'write:at91-sama5d2_xplained_custom.dtb:0x21070000'
Added 180 bytes of padding to align to page size
Error: Command 'write:at91-sama5d2_xplained_custom.dtb:0x21070000': Cannot write past end of memory, only -549912576 bytes remaining at offset 0x21070000 (requested 30976 bytes)
Connection closed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User error.

I found that SAM-BA also has a verification method:

```
# sam-ba -p serial:ttyACM0:115200 -b sama5d2-xplained -a serialflash -c verify:at91-sama5d2_xplained_custom.dtb:0x70000
Opening serial port 'ttyACM0'
Connection opened.
Detected memory size is 4194304 bytes.
Executing command 'verify:at91-sama5d2_xplained_custom.dtb:0x70000'
Added 180 bytes of padding to align to page size
Error: Command 'verify:at91-sama5d2_xplained_custom.dtb:0x70000': Failed verification. First error at file offset 0x00000000
Connection closed.
```

Not good. It turns out that step 5 was missing a very essential step: first you need to erase the flash memory before writing it (I had no idea; I apparently have always used tools that took care of this for me):

```
# sam-ba -p serial:ttyACM0:115200 -b sama5d2-xplained -a serialflash -c erase:0x70000:0x8000
Opening serial port 'ttyACM0'
Connection opened.
Detected memory size is 4194304 bytes.
Executing command 'erase:0x70000:0x8000'
Erased 32768 bytes at address 0x00070000 (100.00%)
Connection closed.

# sam-ba -p serial:ttyACM0:115200 -b sama5d2-xplained -a serialflash -c write:at91-sama5d2_xplained_custom.dtb:0x70000
Opening serial port 'ttyACM0'
Connection opened.
Detected memory size is 4194304 bytes.
Executing command 'write:at91-sama5d2_xplained_custom.dtb:0x70000'
Added 180 bytes of padding to align to page size
Wrote 30976 bytes at address 0x00070000 (100.00%)
Connection closed.

# sam-ba -p serial:ttyACM0:115200 -b sama5d2-xplained -a serialflash -c verify:at91-sama5d2_xplained_custom.dtb:0x70000
Opening serial port 'ttyACM0'
Connection opened.
Detected memory size is 4194304 bytes.
Executing command 'verify:at91-sama5d2_xplained_custom.dtb:0x70000'
Added 180 bytes of padding to align to page size
Verified 30976 bytes at address 0x00070000 (100.00%)
Connection closed.
```